# Search directories and return size / disk space usage for each

Tags: disk-usage, directory-structure, file-search

On my server I have a bunch of accounts that have WordPress installed and also have backup directories in the format: `softaculous_backups`.

I can find all the directories using the command:

```
$ find  / -type d -name "softaculous_backups" -ls
```

I can use commands to check the disk space used by each folder like:

```
$ du -smc * | sort -n
$ du -sh *
```

etc...

But, how do I combine the two commands into one, so I get output like:

```
Size                   Directory
123456789              /home/useraccount/softaculous_backups
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

```
find / -type d -name "softaculous_backups" -exec du -sm {} \; | sort -n
```

For every found directory, `du -sm` is executed. After that all output is sorted numerically.

Comment: Note that you don't need to run one du instance per directory. You can use `-exec du -sm {} +` instead (though the output could be different if some of those directories share files (as hardlinks)). You may (or may not) also want to use `-prune` on those directories to avoid considering `softaculous_backups` directories inside other `softaculous_backups` directories (and save having to look for them inside). The `sort -n` part assumes file paths don't contain newline directories.

Comment: Holy cow that was BRILLIANT! Thanks so much, that works even better than expected!